# TcpClient connected but server not receiving message

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

Server :

```
public class TcpServer
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public TcpServer(string url, int port)
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(url), port);
        pingMapper = new LightPingMapper();
    }


    public void Run()
    {
        tcpListener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server running");
        while (true)
        {
            allDone.Reset();
            tcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket(AcceptCallback, tcpListener);
            Console.WriteLine("Accepting socket");
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            allDone.Set();

            var listener = (TcpListener) result.AsyncState;
            var handler = listener.EndAcceptSocket(result);

            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length, 0, ReadCallback, state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error accepting callback. {e.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            string content = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine("Read data from socket");

            StateObject state = (StateObject) asyncResult.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(asyncResult);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer));
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(content + " "  + DateTime.Now);                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error reading socket. {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}

class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Client:

```
public class TCPClientWrapper
{
    private TcpClient tcpClient;
    private readonly string address;
    private readonly int port;

    public TCPClientWrapper(string address, int port)
    {
        InitTcpClient();
        this.address = address;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void SendMessage()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (!SocketConnected())
            {
                TryConnect();
            }               

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello");
            tcpClient.Client.Send(buffer);
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }
    }

    private void TryConnect()
    {
        bool isConnected = false;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                InitTcpClient();

                tcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(address), port);
                if (SocketConnected())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TcpClient, Connected");
                    isConnected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TcpClient, connection failed. Try to reconnect after 30 seconds, {0}", e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!isConnected)
                {
                    tcpClient.Close();
                    Thread.Sleep(30000);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void InitTcpClient()
    {            
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.SendTimeout = 15;
    }

    private bool SocketConnected()
    {
        var s = tcpClient.Client;

        if (!s.Connected)
            return false;

        bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
        bool part2 = s.Available == 0;
        return !(part1 && part2);
    }

}
```

The problem is that server read only first message , each next message is not received by server . The tcpClient is connected , but server doesn't receive any message . Could anyone suggest what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: You didn't call `handler.BeginReceive` after server receive message in `if (bytesRead > 0)` block, so server stop waiting for next message after the first message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ReadCallback`, you don't start the *next* read - so yes, your code only reads once.

Adding

```cs
handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length, 0, ReadCallback, state);
```

to the bottom of `ReadCallback` (when `bytesRead > 0`) should work. However! You aren't implementing proper framing, so you should be very cautious of that. A basic framing implementation for a text-based protocol (like this) would be to use some kind of line-end sentinel, and buffer data until you see a line-end, *then* process the line.

On TCP, you are only guaranteed to get the right bytes in the right order (or a failed socket eventually) - you are *not* guaranteed to get them in the same composition in terms of calls to `Send` exactly matching calls to `Receive` in terms of the numbers of bytes in each.